# How to use Airflow's xcom_pull feature in the WHERE clause of sql (Snowflake to Google Sheet) operator

Tags: sql, airflow

I have a dag set up in the following manner:

Task 1: Creates a table in snowflake with columns (run_id, A, B, C) using SnowflakeConnectorOperator

Task 2:Python Operator that performs some functionality and also produces a unique string for the run called 'run_id'. I use `ti.xcom_push(key="run_id", value=run_id)`to store this string.I produce the string with the `uuid` library and then type cast it to `str`.

Task 3: Queries the data from Snowflake and populates a google sheet. In this task I want it to populate the google sheet with the data from this run only i.e `where RUN_ID = '{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='Task-2')}}'` however, when I add this where clause the google sheet is blank. It seems to be receiving an empty string here in the xcom. Without the WHERE filter I have a google sheet that has all my data.

I've tried to play around with the way I write `\"{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='Task-2') }}\"` instead of
`where RUN_ID = '{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='Task-2')}}'`. I'm not able to see what the xcom_pull returns. I've checked airflow ui and can confirm that it is successfully pushing the string. However, the pull statement seems to read the string as NONE in the query. Does anyone have input as to how to use xcom in a sql query's where clause where I want to match type string? I've tested the query out in Snowflake with a particular string value and have received a response. I suspect that in my third task there is a type mismatch when filtering with the where clause and that is causing the sheet to be blank.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pull from XCOM the return value from Task-2 which I think doesn't have a return value. You should use xcom_pull(key='run_id') in this case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).